# How to color different ordinal categories in a plot?

Tags: r

I need to color Not Rude, Somewhat Rude, and Very rude with different colors on my mosaic plot.  How I do this?

```
 > table2p
           rbabyF
    hchildF  Not rude Somewhat rude Very rude
        No  65.225564     24.060150 10.714286
        Yes 82.894737     13.157895  3.947368
    > mosaicplot(table2p,  main="Babies vs parents/nonparents", xlab = "Does the person have children?", ylab = "Is it rude to bring baby aboard")
```

Answer (score 0):

`mosaicplot` has an argument `color` (see the [documentation](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~anderson/rw1001/library/base/html/mosaicplot.html)). So this should work:

```
mosaicplot(table2p,  
       main="Babies vs parents/nonparents", 
       xlab = "Does the person have children?", 
       ylab = "Is it rude to bring baby aboard",
       color = c("blue", "red", "green"))
```